# Updating position of 2nd chess piece makes the piece disappear

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, chess

I am teaching myself JS. I am able to move a piece to a new location but for the 2nd piece the chess piece disappears. It seems that the addEventListener is going into a loop and I am not understanding why. Just need to understand what concept am I missing here:
My code below:
chess.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chess board</title>
    <style>
        .cell {
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border: 1.5px solid grey;
            border-style: inset;
        }
 
        .greencell {
            background-color: #AFE1AF;
        }

        .darkgreencell {
            background-color: #097969;
        }
        .redcell {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/chess.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js/chess.js

```
function movep(cbp,cbt,i,j) {
    //Creating rules for pawn
  console.log('P');
    //console.log(cbp);
    //refresh_colors(cbp,cbt);
    if ((i>=0) & (i<=7)) {
        if(cbp[i+1][j].length<2) {
            //Based on player 1, if the location below the pawn is open then cbt masks that as 1
            cbt[i+1][j]=1;
        }
    }
    potential_moves(cbp,cbt,[i,j]);
  update_board(cbp,cbt);
}

var possiblelocs=function(event,i,j,cbp,cbt) {
    //based on string value of cbp (the chess piece of interest) 
  //I have to create rules for possible ways it can go
  if (cbp[i][j].includes('P') ) {movep(cbp,cbt,i,j);}
    //else if (cbp[i][j].includes('K')) {console.log('K');}
    else if (cbp[i][j].includes('N')) {movep(cbp,cbt,i,j);}//using the function for pawn here for debugging purposes
    //else if (cbp[i][j].includes('Q')) {console.log('Q');}
    else if (cbp[i][j].includes('R')) {movep(cbp,cbt,i,j);}//using the function for pawn here for debugging purposes
    //else if (cbp[i][j].includes('B')) {console.log('B');}
    //console.log(cbp);
}

function update_board(cbp,cbt) {
  //fills the board with all the proper pieces
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  //console.log(cbp);
  for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<8;j++) {
        elem[8*i+j].innerHTML=cbp[i][j];
        if (elem[8*i+j].innerHTML.length > 1) {
        //create a clickable EventListener if there is a string value >1 (i.e. not-empty)
            elem[8*i+j].addEventListener( "click",possiblelocs.bind(event,'str',i,j,cbp,cbt) );
        }
    }
  }
}


var movelocs=function(event,i,j,cbp,cbt,pc) {
  //replace old location of string in cbp to the new one
  cbp[i][j]=cbp[pc[0]][pc[1]];
    cbp[pc[0]][pc[1]]='';
  update_board(cbp,cbt);
}

function potential_moves(cbp,cbt,pc) {
  //updates the board with possible location a specific piece can move (based on cbt) 
  //and makes the red cells clickable
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<8;j++) {
        if (cbt[i][j]==1) {
                elem[8*i+j].setAttribute('class', 'cell redcell');
        //once click move the board to the new location
                elem[8*i+j].addEventListener( "click",movelocs.bind(event,'str',i,j,cbp,cbt,pc) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to root cause it but I am unable to root cause even more.
Here is the behavior i see:
When the board starts up:

[image]

After I click 'R11' I see a red square show up down below to see where it can go as show below:
[image]

Once that is completed I see R11 pieces moves down 1 and I also click on N11 to see my available options (I know the rules are not right for those pieces). I then see the following image:
[image]

At this point I click on the red square below N11 and I see that N11 has completely gone. [image]

My best understanding is that movelocs goes into a loop and deletes the piece I just moved. I am not sure why it does that.
If someone has any advice on how to debug this that would helpful as well.

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask strangers to figure out for free. Please provide an [mre]. Simply remove all the logic unrelated to your issue from your code above that still produces the bug. Not only will you help us help you, you will help yourself figure it out!

Comment: The issue should be related to my answer. You can't add new listener every time you click on field.

Comment: try using debug; keyword on your code and watch execution step by step. look it up

Comment: @Inigo i made changes but the code couldn't be removed much because I believe the problem is more structural.

Answer (score 0):

I just went fast through your code and I see potential problem.
In `update_board` you add event listener to all fields. And in the event handler function `possiblelocs` you call `movep` in this function you call `update_board` again. This set another event listener.
So each time you click on field you basically double the number of listeners.

Comment: I think you may be onto something, I am looking into this right now and my gut feel is that you may be onto something.